# Issues deploying an Orchard based website on a virtual/app sub directory

Tags: orchardcms

I have an issue deploying my Orchard based web site on my web hosting.

I need to run 2 Orchard web sites on my web hosting. To do so, I have created 2 sub-directories that are set-up as both application & virtual directories of their own rights :

- **~/site1**
- **~/site2**

Finally I have set-up two domain names :

- **mysite1.com** pointing to my host's vdir **~/site1**
- **mysite2.com** pointing to my host's vdir **~/site2**

My page works when I go to mysite1.com main page, or mysite1.com/Admin (hard path ?!).
But they don't work when the page slurp points to Orchard dynamic pages/content. 
It then gives me lots of :

> HTTP 404. The resource cannot be found

Do you have any ideas what could be happening please ?

ps: I have also posted more details on the [Orchard forum](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/437490)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't just need to be vdirs, they need to be full IIS applications, under a ASP.NET 4.0 integrated pipeline app pool, with full trust. (please don't cross post)

Comment: Hi Bertrand,
according to my web hosts ( webhost4life.com ) everything is working correctly on their server and is set-up as your feedback indicates it, but clearly all permalinks are not working and all administration tasks like adding, removing items still don't work. They asked me to check with the CMS constructor. Would you have any other ideas of what could be happening ?
Thanks

Comment: No, all recent logs are empty (0 bytes). There is an old one with the following content : `ettings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetDescriptorRecord() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Settings\Descriptor\ShellDescriptorManager.cs:line 57 [..]`
My host doesn't want to give me IIS logs and according to them, there is nothing noteworthy in them.

Comment: I have changed the log4net setting to log ALL. And here is the [log file I have](http://db.tt/dLTGyFjy). 'Not found' happens in line 35439. Hopefully this will be more helpful than my previous comment.

Comment: The file you're linking to is not publicly accessible. Please post the stack trace here.

Comment: Try this one instead : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21455379/orchard-error-2013.03.27.log.7z
Unfortunately, the trace is too big to be posted with the character limitation.

Comment: Yes I can access the admin console and navigate through the menus, even change a few settings. But I cannot make changes like adding/editing/removing content items or activating/deactivating a module.
Also all the pages are really slow to load. I wonder if there are some timeout happening somewhere..

Comment: Then there seems to be something wrong with Autoroute. Not sure what, but this shows that some routes are OK, but Autoroute's aren't.

Comment: Could it be maybe that IIS is configured in a way that prevents catchall route like Autoroute's from working?

Comment: I should have answered this thread a long time ago so my apoligize for not closing this earlier. As it pans out, the web host support got confused with all the ASP.NET version installed and didn't have the latest installed :( Anyway, thank you for your precious help Bertrand, much appreciated.

Comment: Please feel free to show your appreciation by granting the answer ;)